Is it possible to use MapLibre without webGL
Online I found that it was possible to use mapbox js as a fallback for mapboxGL js. I a similar approach also possible for mapLibre?
When I disable webGL in my browser I notice that my mapLibre app crashes and I was wondering to still have the app working even when webGL is not present.
